# Ruby on rails active record: update a field by another field in the same record using update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I use **update_all** for the following purpose:

```
UPDATE  table_name set field1=field2 * 2 where id = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails4, you can do

```
Model.where(id: 1).update_all("field = field2 * 2")
```

In Previous versions of Rails, you can pass condition to `update_all`, like this

```
Model.update_all("field = field2 * 2", {:id => 1})
```

**NOTE:**

[update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) does **not** trigger Active Record callbacks or validations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your intention, but if you're just trying to do a 1 time update of all records that mach id = 1 running this in your console should work.

```
Model.where("id = 1").each { |n|  (n.field1 = n.field2*2)}
```